# How To Add Firebase Rules To Specific User To read And Write And all other User only read?

Tags: flutter, firebase

I Have Created firebase and flutter app and google is sending me emails saying firebase rules are not good. How do I make those rules better? I want to give permission to login users to read and my account to read and write permission.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that will help you.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Make sure the uid of the requesting user matches name of the user
    // document. The wildcard expression {userId} makes the userId variable
    // available in rules.
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a correct way you can secure database.

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Line below secure whole database so users are not alowed to create any new collections etc.
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
    match /app/{dataId} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if isAdmin();
    }
    match /posts/{dataId} {
        allow read: if resource.data.isPublic == true || isAdmin();
        allow write: if isAdmin();
    }
  }
}

function isAdmin() {
    return request.auth.token.admin == true;
}
```

Users don't have any `.admin` variables. You have to assign them using firebase functions. Read about custom claims.